# Publish a Windows Application Package Project via command line

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, solution, desktop-bridge

### How can I publish the UWP package via command line?

I have a WPF application that is packaged with a `Windows Application Package Project` that ends up being published to the Microsoft Store.

In order to be accepted in the Store, the WPF project needs to be compiled with a preprocessor directive (that I named as "UWP"), deactivating stuff that are not allowed for Store apps.

I'm in the process of migrating the WPF app from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5 and along with that I'm trying to streamline my publishing process via command line.

---

### Is there any way to configure or update the package to support ARM64?

The app will be published outside the Store as x86, x64 and ARM64 and I intend to do the same for the Store version.

When checking the WAPP, I noticed that ARM64 is not available on the list. As you can see in the screenshot, I was able to create a ARM64 build profile, but the architecture is not available on the table.

[image: Publish]

---

### What have I tried? (Command line issue)

I tried running this command:

`MSBuild.exe C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj /p:DefineConstants=UWP /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM64" /p:OutDir="..\Publish\UWP"`

But got these errors:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 29/09/2021 22:09:19.
Project "C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1718,5): warning NU1702: ProjectReference 'C:\Project\Project.csproj' was resolved using '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0' instead of the project target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1718,5): warning NU1702: ProjectReference 'C:\Project\Project.csproj' was resolved using '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0' instead of the project target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj]
_ResolveVCLibDependencies:
  Searching for SDKs targeting "UAP, 10.0.20348.0".
Project "C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj" (1) is building "C:\Project\Project.csproj" (2:9) on node 1 (publish target(s)).
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'C:\Project\Project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0-windows/win-x86'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0-windows' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x86' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [C:\Project\Project.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Project\Project.csproj" (publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1718,5): warning NU1702: ProjectReference 'C:\Project\Project.csproj' was resolved using '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0' instead of the project target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1718,5): warning NU1702: ProjectReference 'C:\Project\Project.csproj' was resolved using '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0' instead of the project target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'. This project may not be fully compatible with your project. [C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj]


"C:\Project-UWP\Project.UWP\Project.UWP.wapproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Project\Project.csproj" (publish target) (2:9) ->
(ResolvePackageAssets target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'C:\Project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0-windows/win-x86'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0-windows' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x86' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [C:\Project\Project.csproj]

    2 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.31
```

Notice that there are warnings related to framework references:

```
ProjectReference C:\Project\Project.csproj was resolved using .NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0 instead of the project target framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1. 
This project may not be fully compatible with your project. Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 1719
```

The WPF project was set to use .NET 5, so I don't see why there's any reference to .NETCoreApp 6 or .NET Framework 4.5.1.

---

### What have I tried? (Missing ARM64 issue)

I created a WAPP from scratch and saw that the option for ARM64 appeared in the architecture table.

[image]

But when publishing manually via the context menu, I'll get this error:

```
The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win-ARM64' is not recognized.
```

Comment: Manarin:  Any updates?

Comment: @pedda Yes, here's my current publishing process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368227/how-to-distribute-arm64-app-in-the-microsoft-store-as-a-wap-project/70477566#70477566